# Use a different node_modules directory for different versions of Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, nvm

When using NVM, or otherwise switching between Node.js versions, node_modules has to be rebuilt for each Node version. Would it be possible somehow use a different node_modules directory for each version, instead of having to rebuild the contents everytime you switch between versions?

something like:

```
node_modules_v8/
node_modules_v7/
node_modules_v6/
```

Maybe there is a better way to do this, not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three suggestions (in my order of pref):

1. Use Docker to help configure [Containers](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#container-and-layers) and [Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to switch up where things point to based on your version of node.
2. Set a symbolic link ([Linux syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1951752/271992), [Windows syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17246581/271992)) to your `node_modules` folder that points to the correct version of modules that `node` expects to run.
3. Similar to manipulating symbolic links, use the [`NODE_PATH`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_path_path) setting and point it to the correct cache of your `node_modules` folder (i.e. NODE_PATH=/etc/node_v8) just prior to executing your `node` command. If you set it globally it would restrict you running multiple instances of node on that box so, you'd need to set the `NODE_PATH` on a per process instance.

Comment: nice answer, will probably try one of these out soon

Comment: Symlink for Windows really helped me